# I want to display all the records from the Table using For loop

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.6

Here in this code i have to display all the records from the Table(cust_college). but this function is returning me only 1'st row of that table not other rows.please tell me solution

```
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$a = "SELECT * from cust_college";

$qry = $read->query($a);
$res = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //fetch row
foreach ($res as $payment) {
    echo $payment = $res[college];
    echo $payment = $res[value_id];
    echo $payment = $res[shop_id];
    echo $payment = $res[cust_address];
}

$store = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
```

Comment: Your own comment says it all: //fetch row not //fetch all rows

Comment: Hey Mark i did all the probability with the fetch_ASSOC but still getting 1 row multiple times

Comment: You should create a model to access the table ... 
this is the right way to work with magento and db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = $read->getSelect()->getAdapter()->fetchAll('SELECT * from cust_college');
```

Comment: Hi Guerra thanks for replying but this query is not running . please tell me different code to run

Comment: Hey Guerra thank you very much. My Query is running .